# What does setEmailAddressIdentifierSupported() do for google's Android Smartlock HintRequest?

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

We are currently reenable our smartlock hint request feature for our android app.
I noticed that that there's a method called `setEmailAddressIdentifierSupported()`
And pass true or false actually returns us different set of accounts. I read the doc already but cant understand:

> Enables returning credential hints where the identifier is an email
>   address, intended for use with a password chosen by the user.

Shouldnt the hint request just return a list of accounts (like email or something) ? What does it do with passwords?

Also, we noticed that smartlock hint request returns us different sets of accounts in different version of our app. I Dont know if it is related to the setting above.

Will be good if anyone can help us on this ;)