# Success callback of the smartlock save API never fire

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

Im using the google smart lock android sdk to implement the saving password feature, but I found out that the success callback for save method never fire.

```
 Auth.CredentialsApi.save(mSmartLockApiClient, credential).setResultCallback(
                    new FragmentResolvingResultCallbacks<Status>(mFragment, RC_CREDENTIALS_SAVE) {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Status status) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onUnresolvableFailure(Status status) {

                        }
                    });
```

Is there any reason why?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Qing, do you mean that it's always resolution required, and not success? Success is only used when no resolution is required, e.g. when saving a Google Sign-In account or updating an existing saved password, which does not require a dialog. Let me know if that answers your question!

Comment: hey @StevenSoneff , ok i think i understand the concept now, so if you wanna track the event for saving credentials, seems like the best place is in onActivityResult() right?  thank you ;)

Comment: also i got another issue for requesting hints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381721/what-does-setemailaddressidentifiersupported-do-for-googles-android-smartlock if you can take a look at this , thanks